# Custom Cross-Referencing of Figure does not work in HTML output

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, acm, acmart

I'm currently creating the final version of a paper published at ACM. In my main latex file I declared the following command:

```
\newcommand*{\myref}[2][]{%
  \hyperref[{#2}]{%
    \ref*{#2}#1}%
}
```

I use this command as follows: `Figure~\myref[A]{fig:smartphone_wild:gui}`. This results in “Figure 2A”.
The effect is that both the number an character are linked (e.g. in Figure 2A, “2A” is linked to the figure and not only “2”).

I have submitted my paper to the ACM publishing system (TAPS) and I got back a PDF and a HTML version. The linking worked fine for the pdf version but in the HTML version no link is set.

Is there another way to do this? I don’t want to use subfigures because I have encoded the enumeration (A, B etc.) in the figure itself and optimized the placement (in addition, certain figures cannot be split in subfigures because they are connected)

Comment: Do you know what conversion tool they use for the LaTeX to HTML conversion? I cannot find any details, but it is impossible to answer without it.

Comment: @michal.h21 No, I don't. I also asked them but I did not get an answer yet.